# there were houses in whch they could not be inserted

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a quote" from "The Social Triangle" by O Henry:

Bill McMahan had a wife, and upon her visiting cards was engraved the name "Mrs. William Darragh McMahan." And there was a certain vexation attendant upon these cards; for, **small as they were,** **there** **were houses in which they could not be inserted**.  Billy McMahan was a dictator in politics, a four-walled tower in business, a mogul, dread, loved and obeyed among his own people.

I am not able to tell if the part in bold is used figuratively.  I'd appreciate it very much if you can paraphrase it in plain English.

Comment: It seems to be a reference to the 19th century social custom of leaving 'visiting cards' with your name on at other people's homes as a preliminary to exchanging social calls. Mrs. McMahan probably felt unable to leave cards with people who were considered to be too much her social superiors. The reference to the size of the cards is figurative; the impossibility was nothing to do with their size.

Comment: It's certainly "whimsical", but not "figurative". The calling cards really *are* "inserted" into houses (possibly through the letter-box, but perhaps by being handed to the butler who just opened the front door).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paragraph has to do with the now outdated custom of leaving calling cards at the homes of people you went (physically) to visit.  If the person was not "at home", you generally left a card in a tray that was presented (by a butler or maid) specifically for that purpose.  Please note; It was not uncommon to be declared "not at home" when you were, and the employee collecting the cards could be pretty snobby, too, thus discouraging the deposit of such a card.  These calling cards were generally proffered during certain morning hours when such drop in visits were encouraged or expected.

Presumably, then, Mrs. William Darragh McMahan was either too timid to proffer them at these homes where the residents were too much higher on the social scale for her to feel comfortable doing so, or she had tried, perhaps once and been re-buffed.

Too much should not be made of this one sentence, it is merely O Henry setting up and describing the social position of one of his protagonists in relation to others in his short story. The sentence is used figuratively.

In fact, it is a typically elegant short story of O Henry's which shows in a humorous fashion how silly and different the different kinds of snob appeal in human society can be. The short story can be read online at the url below for free.
http://www.online-literature.com/o_henry/trimmed-lamp/12/

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Your answer is very helpful.